# Why i cannot display the error message in the login page?

Tags: php, html

i want to display my error message in the login form by getting the result from the login.php ,here is the sample code that i have use.The first part is the index.php

```
<?
include("login.php");?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Hup Seng</h1>
        <div id="login">
            <h2>Login Form</h2>
            <form action="login.php" method="post">
                <label>UserName :</label>
                <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text" required>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Password :</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password" required>
                <br>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
                    <span><?php  echo $error; ?></span>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the login.php i have put the error message under the else statement in order to pass the information to the login form

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
//if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (isset($_POST['username']) || isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // Define $username and $password
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $pw = encode($password);
    $sql = "SELECT count(ID) as cid FROM tblUser WHERE UserId = '$username' and Password1 = '$pw'";
    $rs = odbc_exec($link_mssql,$sql);
    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
        $count=odbc_result($rs,"cid");
    }
    if ($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username; // Initializing Session
        header("location: homepage.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
    } else {
        $error="username/passwod combination incorrect";
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    odbc_close($link_mssql); // Closing Connection
}
//}
?>
```

Comment: by using `header` after setting the `$error` variable the value is immediately lost when the page redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['error']="username/passwod combination incorrect";
```

and in login form check

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
echo $_SESSION['error'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to add `header` you already including `login.php` file in `index.php`

```
 $error="username/passwod combination incorrect";
 //header("location: index.php");//remove this line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//header("location: index.php");
```

Remove this or you can redirect the page after some time if you want like this.

```
header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" ); // page redirect after 5sec
```